# Nginx loading multiple react App

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have three react apps, they are stored in the same server. The nginx config file "/etc/nginx/sites-available/default" is as below. The location of the react app is /home/ubuntu/team/react-referral/build, /home/ubuntu/team/react-fulfillment/build and /home/ubuntu/team/react-leader/build. When i type the url in the browser, such as "http://x.x.x.x/referral/", the url can be written to "http://x.x.x.x/react-referral/build/". But the browser shows empty page. May i know what is the mistake that i make?  Thank you.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /home/ubuntu/team;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name x.x.x.x;

    location / { 
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /referral {
        rewrite ^/referral /react-referral/build permanent;
    }

    location /fulfillment {
        rewrite ^/fulfillment /react-fulfillment/build permanent;
    }

    location /leader {
        #rewrite ^/leader /react-leader/build permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's a blank page and not an nginx 404 page, that means it must be loading something. Have you checked the source of the responded page to see if it's your html template? Could be something with how you have react-router configured. Also check for javascript errors, and see if something is breaking before first render.

Comment: if i set the root to /home/ubuntu/team/react-referral/build , as in "root  
    /home/ubuntu/team/react-referral/build;"   that react app can be loaded. So there is no error in that react app. About react-router, i have not configured it

Comment: react-router is used for react app that has multiple views. I have 3 different react app. Can i use react-router for routing the url ?

Comment: I have found the solution. Use react-router, and add the individual components to the main react app, and use react-router to send the url request to the react components.

Comment: the link is a useful guide for react-router https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf